# print values from an xml output

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk

I am working on a script, which returns output in xml format and wanted to print just the value of a particular attribute.

As an example, here is the output of the script :

```
~#] ./test.sh resource list --platform=centos

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ResourcesResponse>
<Status>Success</Status>
<Resource id="11087" name="centos"
```

Now, I wanted to print only the Resource id which is 11087. When I used awk along with NR, it returns as below :

```
~#] ./test.sh resource list --platform=centos | awk 'NR==4{print $2}'

id="11087"
```

Could you please help know how to print only the value, i.e 11087

Comment: A note: When dealing with `xml` data, it is _generally_ not recommended to assume that the field you want is always at n'th position in the line. because `<tag param1="value1" param2="value2">` is usually equivalent to `<tag param2="value2" param1="value1">`. However, if you are generating the xml from your own code, this point may be irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using `xmlstarlet` with XPath query :

```
$ ./test.sh resource list --platform=centos|xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/ResourcesResponse/Resource/@id' -v '.' -n
11087
$ xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/ResourcesResponse/Resource/@id' -v '.' -n < <(./test.sh resource list --platform=centos)
11087
```

It's always better to use tools optimized for XML parsing (`xmlstarter`, `xmllint`, or more powerful shells languages ​​like perl, python, php cli mode, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should give what you want.

```
awk -F\" 'NR==4{print $2}' file
11087
```

By setting Field Separator to `"` your data are in the second field.

To make sure you get correct `id`, I would have used:

```
awk -F\" '/Resource id/ {print $2}' file
11087
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
~#] ./test.sh resource list --platform=centos | sed -nr '4 s/.*id="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'
11087
```

Notes:

- The `-n` option to `sed` tells it not print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- The `-r` option to `sed` tells it to use extended regular expressions
- The `sed` command `4 s/old/new/p` tells it to operate on only on line 4 and, on that line, look for `old` and replace it with `new` and, only if that substitution happened, print the line.
- In our case, the value of `old` is `.*id="([^"]+)".*/`.  Since this starts with `.*` and ends with `.*`, it matches the whole line.  It also captures the value of the id in match variable 1.
- The value of `new` is simply `\1` which is the value of the id.

Comment: you could also use `sed -rn '4s/.*"([0-9]+)".*/\1/p' file`

Answer (score 2):

grep variant:

```
grep -m1 -oP '(?<=id=")[0-9]*(?=")' file
```

Or with input piped from your command:

```
~#] ./test.sh resource list --platform=centos | grep -m1 -oP '(?<=id=")[0-9]*(?=")' 
11087
```

Explanation:
Print only (`-o`) first match (`-m1`) of number (`[0-9]*`) prefixed by `id="` (`(?<=id=")`) & followed by a `"` (`(?=")`).

Comment: Assuming numerical `id` parameter. Change `[0-9]*` to `[^"]*`, if it can be non-numeric.

Comment: If there are more than four line and other `id`, this will get all `id`.